# Unable to read complete file with below Java Code

Tags: java, filereader

While Reading a file below part of code works fine

//Code A

```
         try{
              String s1;
              f = new FileReader("C:\\Test.txt");
              f1 = new BufferedReader(f);
              while((s1 = f1.readLine())!=null)
              {
              System.out.println(s1);
              } 
            }
```

But this one not:

//Code B

```
      try{
             String s1;
             f = new FileReader("C:\\Test.txt");
             f1 = new BufferedReader(f);        
           while((f1.readLine())!=null)
           {
           s1=f1.readLine();
           System.out.println(s1);
          }
    }
```

I think both Code A and B are the same; but code A read full contents of file while code B not. Why?

Comment: In code B example the readLine method is called twice in each loop.  Once in the while evaluation and once in the loop. Only the readLine method in the loop is printed out. (Also note that the null test only applies to the condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Code B you call `readLine()` twice in one iteration thus reading 2 lines in one iteration and end up only printing every second line. Even if you don't assign the `f1.readLine()` to anything the line is still read and the reader goes ahead to the next line.